# How to make logical AND in mongoose findOne query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've had a problem with logical AND operation in mongoose findOne function.

Date provide to this function is correct, i was checking and logging result. I am still getting OR instead of AND operation.

```
static checkAvaiable(date, time, number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(date, time)
        TableModel.findOne({
            $and: [
                {
                    'reservations.date': date,
                    'reservations.time': time,
                    number
                }
            ]
        }, { 'reservations.$': 1 }, (err, result) => {

            if (result.reservations.length != 0) {
                reject()
            }

            if (err) {
                reject()
            }
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `$and` operator wrong, please refer to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).
being said that it seems that you won't need to use the `$and` operator at all. you can just filter by your arguments the default behavior is to use `and` logic.

```
static checkAvaiable(date, time, number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(date, time)
        TableModel.findOne({
            $and: [
                {
                    'reservations.date': date
                },
                {
                    'reservations.time': time
                },
                {
                    number
                }
            ]
        }, { 'reservations.$': 1 }, (err, result) => {

            if (result.reservations.length != 0) {
                reject()
            }

            if (err) {
                reject()
            }
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```